# mysql trigger - select count(*) from trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to count rows created/inside (dont know what it is called) a trigger.

like i have a trigger :

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `mydb`.`tn_air_staff_leave_application`
AFTER INSERT ON `mydb`.`staff_leave_application`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
----
----
----
END$$
```

and want to know how many rows trigger is going to create, I need this value inside trigger:

```
set @newrows:= (select count(*) from tn_air_staff_leave_application);
```

is it possible?? if not any other solution out there???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is a purely passive piece of code which is executed before or after a row is inserted, updated or deleted from a table in your database.

The trigger can not be executed actively anc thus does not have a return value you can read.

What you can do is to let your trigger write a value into another table or into a session variable which then can be queried for in an extra query.

You can not store a whole result row or a result set of several rows into a session variable <s>like you are trying in your example.</s>

In MySQL the trigger is always executed `FOR EACH ROW`, means within the trigger you will only look at one row, not at several.

**EDIT:**

Actually your example query returns a single value, so this would work. (would deliver the amount of total records in your `tn_air_staff_leave_application` table into the local session variable `@newrows`)

For more specific help you would need to be more specific on what you're trying to do